# Is scipy.stats.gaussian_kde supposed to overwrite weights?

Tags: python, scipy

scipy.stats.gaussian_kde takes a keyword argument weights.  Internally the weights are normalized, but it is not copied first.  The upshot being that if a numpy array of values are passed in these will be normalized as a side effect...

```
import scipy.stats as sts
import numpy as np

values = np.random.lognormal(size=1000)
weights = np.random.choice([1.0,10.0,100.0], size=len(values))
sum(weights)
```

Sum of weights will be about 40,000

```
kde_pdf = sts.kde.gaussian_kde(np.log10(values), weights=weights)
```

Sum of weights will now be ~1.0

Nasty side effect.

Comment: For a question such as this, you should also create a bug report at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues; click the green "New issue" button to get started with the bug report.

Comment: Done, I think - not done that before :).

Comment: Thanks for submitting the bug report!

Comment: This has been [fixed in scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9709)